# How to perform CRUD operations for multiple records in CAKEPHP

Tags: cakephp

My task is to upload file to folder and its details to database its working fine if i have one record in a form but if i have multiple rows then its really giving errors i searched out for many links but couldn't find the answer.

Used save All, Save Many, all functions but still unable to perform it.

Please provide full code if anyone can.

My Controller

```
public function add() 
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {
        $this->File->create();
        if(empty($this->data['File']['url']['name']))
        {
            unset($this->request->data['url']['file']);
        }
        if(!empty($this->data['File']['url']['name']))
        {
            $file=$this->data['File']['url'];
            $file['name']=$this->sanitize($file['name']);
            $this->request->data['File']['url'] = time().$file['name'];

            if($this->File->save($this->request->data))
            {
                move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], APP . 'outsidefiles' .DS. time().$file['name']); 
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index')); 
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your File has been saved.'));
                //return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your File.'));
    }
}
```

.ctp file

```
<h1>Add File</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('File',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));

 echo $this->Form->input('category', array(
            'options' => array( 'passport' => 'Passport', 'pancard' => 'Pancard', 'driving license' => 'Driving License', 'others' => 'Others')
        ));

        echo $this->Form->input('type', array(
            'options' => array( 'image' => 'Image', 'office' => 'Office', 'technical' => 'Technical', 'others' => 'Others')
        ));

  echo $this->Form->input('reference');

echo $this->Form->input('url', array('type' => 'file'));


 echo $this->Form->input('category', array(
            'options' => array( 'passport' => 'Passport', 'pancard' => 'Pancard', 'driving license' => 'Driving License', 'others' => 'Others')
        ));

        echo $this->Form->input('type', array(
            'options' => array( 'image' => 'Image', 'office' => 'Office', 'technical' => 'Technical', 'others' => 'Others')
        ));

  echo $this->Form->input('reference');

echo $this->Form->input('url', array('type' => 'file'));


echo $this->Form->end('Save File');
?>
```

Comment: `if i have multiple rows then its really giving errors` - what errors?

Comment: It doesnt map the fields of form to the database it just map the last row to the database

Comment: That isn't an error (message). It's not clear what problem you have.

Comment: I am not having any error my problem is i want to save more than 1 rows to a database but i am unable to do this i am submitting my form but its just saving one record not all

Comment: It is not helpful to provide code that does one thing - and then basically ask for someone to provide you the code to do something else; the code in the question doesn't look to attempt to bulk-save anything. _Demonstrate a problem_.