# How to upload bulk records in CAKEPHP

Tags: php, cakephp

A 4 column dashboard with 10 rows is

provided wherein the user can enter

details as follows:

```
Column 1 – File Category
Column 2 – File Type
Column 3 - File Reference
Column 4 – Upload FIle (any type)
```

Upload button– uploads the details of 
all the documents entered 
simultaneously

I am unable to upload all records in database only last recording is saving in DATABASE kindly help me

UserControlle.php (my controller)

```
<?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class FilesController extends AppController
{
    public $helpers=array('Html','Form');

    public $components = array('RequestHandler');   

    /*function to display all files details*/
    public function index() 
    {
        $this->set('Files', $this->File->find('all'));
    }

    /*function to add file record into the database */
    public function add() 
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) 
        {
            $this->File->create();
            if(empty($this->data['File']['url']['name']))
            {
                unset($this->request->data['url']['file']);
            }
            if(!empty($this->data['File']['url']['name']))
            {
                $file=$this->data['File']['url'];
                $file['name']=$this->sanitize($file['name']);
                $this->request->data['File']['url'] = time().$file['name'];

                if($this->File->save($this->request->data))
                {
                    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], APP . 'outsidefiles' .DS. time().$file['name']); 
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index')); 
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your File has been saved.'));
                    //return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                }
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your File.'));
        }
    }

}
```

add.ctp (my view)

```
<h1>Add File</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('File',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));

echo $this->Form->input('category', array(
            'options' => array( 'passport' => 'Passport', 'pancard' => 'Pancard', 'driving license' => 'Driving License', 'others' => 'Others')
        ));

        echo $this->Form->input('type', array(
            'options' => array( 'image' => 'Image', 'office' => 'Office', 'technical' => 'Technical', 'others' => 'Others')
        ));

echo $this->Form->input('reference');

echo $this->Form->input('url', array('type' => 'file'));

echo $this->Form->input('category', array(
            'options' => array( 'passport' => 'Passport', 'pancard' => 'Pancard', 'driving license' => 'Driving License', 'others' => 'Others')
        ));

        echo $this->Form->input('type', array(
            'options' => array( 'image' => 'Image', 'office' => 'Office', 'technical' => 'Technical', 'others' => 'Others')
        ));

echo $this->Form->input('reference');

echo $this->Form->input('url', array('type' => 'file'));

echo $this->Form->input('category', array(
            'options' => array( 'passport' => 'Passport', 'pancard' => 'Pancard', 'driving license' => 'Driving License', 'others' => 'Others')
        ));

        echo $this->Form->input('type', array(
            'options' => array( 'image' => 'Image', 'office' => 'Office', 'technical' => 'Technical', 'others' => 'Others')
        ));

echo $this->Form->input('reference');

echo $this->Form->input('url', array('type' => 'file'));

echo $this->Form->end('Save File');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to perform CRUD operations for multiple records in CAKEPHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31499699/how-to-perform-crud-operations-for-multiple-records-in-cakephp)

Comment: If this is a different question, it still looks to contain the same code as your other open question. Please do not create duplicate questions (or ping multiple people on twitter to answer your duplicate question) _especially_ as the comments left on your duplicate question remain essentially unactioned.

Answer (score 0):

How would this bulk save anything? It looks like you are saving the uploaded file to the db. Also it is not a good idea to name a model `File` as it conflicts with a core class that can cause a bunch of problems.

Generally if you want to bulk insert, you would want to read the rows out of the CSV, loop over them and call `create()` and `save()` on each one.

Comment: Dear Mark Story i am new to CakePHP and i dont know how to do it through .csv files please share some links from where i can understand the procedure